# Unit test a private method via a protected method in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I've these two methods from my `MetadataManagement` class which I'd like to unit test:

```java
@Override
protected void doPut(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
    final MetadataResource resource)
    throws IOException {
  ServiceCommon.checkRole(getSubject(request));

  if (resource.getType() != Type.CONTAINER) {
    final String err = "Request not allowed for " + request.getURI();
    throw new ServiceApiException(ServiceApiError.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, err);
  }

  final String name = getContainerName(resource);

  final ServiceApiMetadata config = getConfig(request, PATH);

  final StorageLocation storageLocation = getStorageLocation(conf.getStorageLocation());

  if (config.getNotifications() != null) {
    checkMethodSupported(id);
    checkService(id);
  }
}

private ServiceApiMetadata getConfig(final HttpServletRequest request, final String path)
    throws IOException {
  final Schema schema;
  try (final InputStream inStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)) {
    final JSONObject origSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inStream));
    if (isGoldStar()) {
      origSchema.getJSONObject("properties")
          .getJSONObject("notifications")
          .getJSONObject("properties")
          .getJSONObject("topic")
          .put("pattern", "^[0-9A-Za-z-.]*$");
    }
    schema = SchemaLoader.load(origSchema);
  }

  final ServiceApiMetadata config;
  try (final BufferedReader reader = request.getReader()) {
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));
    schema.validate(json);
    config = ServiceApiMetadata.read(json);
  } catch (final ValidationException e) {
    _logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    if (e.getLocation().contains("#/properties/notifications")) {
      throw new ServiceApiException(ServiceApiError.MALFORMED_NOTIFICATIONS_ERROR,
          ServiceApiErrorMessage.MALFORMED_JSON);
    } else {
      throw new ServiceApiException(ServiceApiError.MALFORMED_JSON);
    }
  } catch (final JSONException e) {
    _logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    throw new ServiceApiException(ServiceApiError.MALFORMED_JSON);
  }

  return config;
}
```

As I understand it I can not directly call `getConfig` in my test because the method is `private`. I believe using reflection is an option but is not advised. Based on that, any test of `getConfig` should be done through `doPut`.

What I'm most interested in checking is if `getConfig.isGoldStar` is true, the `origSchema` pattern updates to `^[0-9A-Za-z]*$` and if it is false it remains at `^[0-9A-Za-z-._]*$`.

To call `doPut` in my test I will need `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse` and `MetadataResource` objects. I'm not sure how I generate these. `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are from `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` and `MetadataResource` comes from within my project. It takes `HttpServletRequest` and an enum as parameters.

How do I do this test? I think I should be OK once I can call the `doPut` method but I'm struggling to do that.

Comment: The spring-test library has `MockHttpServlet*` implementations that can be passed in for such use cases.

Comment: You should not test your private methods. It breaks the encapsulation. If there is a significant piece of logic in your private method - you probably have to extract it to a separate public class and test that class instead.

Comment: Thanks @user2478398. Looking at that now.

@Ziumin what about testing the `getConfig` response? It should have the pattern value I want to test.

Comment: If that's acceptable to you, you could declare the method as package private, so tests in the same package can access it. (less clean than extracting classes, but much less change is required.)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or  ( that this question very much duplicates)